# Android Firebase Remove An Item From A List

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to remove an item from a list in the database. It was added with `.push()`.

Here is an example:

[image]

For instance, I would like to remove "8mtuj28..." from the list (and I have the key btw).

Here is an example of some code I expected to work:

```
//remove poll from author's list of polls
authorRef.child(getString(R.string.my_polls_ref)).child(pollIds.get(currentPoll)).removeValue();
```

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT:**

I have realized that I needed to use an integer for the key instead of a string. I was completely ignoring the numbers in front of the poll keys. I think I will change all of this to a Map instead of a list.

Comment: would you mind adding some code that you have tried

Comment: @OlegBogdanov I have added a small piece of code.

Comment: I don't immediately see what's wrong with the snippet you posted. What's the problem?

Comment: It doesn't do anything to the database

Comment: It's hard to be certain with the current snippet. Does it work if you use hard-coded values: `authorRef.child("myPolls").child(3).removeValue()`? If that doesn't work either, try attaching an error listener: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/19721/detect-errors-when-writing-a-value-on-android#t=201612311543389825732

Answer (score 1):

that is my solution but i have a jsobject in my list

```
    String value = "valor";
    Sting key = "key";                                                          
    Query query = mDatabase.child(path).child(mFirebaseAuth.getUid());
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                for(DataSnapshot du : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    if(value.contentEquals(du.child(key).getValue().toString())){
                        mDatabase.child(path).child(mFirebaseAuth.getUid()).child(du.getKey()).removeValue();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

// from key you can get 0,1,2,3,4,... value of firebase db.

if you know that value like here for your **key is 1** for your **8mtu**....

```
ref.child("myPolls").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        // you can pass here that value instead of **1**
                        ref.child("myPolls).child("1").setValue(null);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Ya... the problem now is that I don't know the integer key. All I know know is the String ("8mtu...")

Answer (score 0):

```
for (DataSnapshot childSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    final String key = childSnapShot.getKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if got the answer you need but this should remove an item from the list. You ultimately just have to drill down to the node that you want to get removed.

```
firebase.database().ref('uft0jep4knqlnum...').remove();
```

From "Delete data" Section at

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write
[image: Remove Item from Firebase database]

Answer (score 0):

If you are viewing items from Firebase database onto the recyclerview/list and trying to remove each item per click or swipe to delete, this solution is for you:
First, lets assume we a List listOfApples = new ArrayList<>(); and it has some data in it.

```
public void removeItems(int position, DatabaseReference ref){
String appleName = "";
double applePrice = 0.0;
for(int i = 0; i < listOfApples.size(); i++){
if(i == position){
appleName = listOfApples.get(i).getAppleName();
applePrice = listOfApples.get(i).getApplePrice();
listOfApples.remove(position);
notifyDataChanged();
notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount);
}
}
final String finalAppleName = appleName;
final double finalApplePrice = applePrice;
ValueEventListener removeListener = new ValueEventListener(){ 
@Override
public void onDataChanged(@NonNull DataSnapShot dataSnapshot(){
for(DataSnapshot snapShot: dataSnapShot().getChildren()){
if(snapShot != null){
Apple apple = snapShot.getValue(Apple.class);
if(apple != null){
if(apple.getAppleName().equals(finalAppleName) && apple.getApplePrice() == finalApplePrice){
if(ref != null && snapShot.getKey() != null){
ref.child(snapShot.getKey()).removeValue(new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener(){
@Override
 public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError databaseError, @NonNull DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
// show a message or do whatever you feel like
});
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
}
@Override
 public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
};
ref.addValueEventListener(removeListener);
}
```

Thats all it. Now, here's one caveat with this solution that I want to point out, we are deleting the item from the recyclerview first and then we are deleting it from the firebase database. What if user gets disconnected from network while removing an item? Some of you might be okay with with that because you can just show a message to your user that failed to remove because of some issues.For those who are not okay with it, you can remove that item in onComplete(..) method, notify the adapter and refresh/recreate the activity.